# How to compute this greedy complexity

Tags: set, greedy

Can anyone help me to compute this complexity?

[image]

What i think is :

Line 1 is an O(nlogn) for the sort.

Then,I have to compute for every node (line 2, while (U!=0) ) two stars for the node.

Compute one star for all nodes its cost O(|E|), but my problem is the second star.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any clue as to what these stars are? does the second star have O(|E|) as well? if so it should be O(n*|E|*|E| + n*log(n)), if I remember correctly

Comment: Star of node x , is the set of nodes y such that (x,y) is an edge of graph.

Comment: Hm... If you do not have a neighboring table, that would be O(n), otherwise O(constant) I believe

Comment: Well, you can have a table for each node that holds the nodes with a line connecting them to said node, which will cost some more in memory, but then you run the loop only for the nodes in the table, thus it runs in constant time (which I assume is what you mean with O(|E|) ). The other way to do it is not keep a list of the connected nodes, but find them during run time, this means you will have to iterate through them, which means n repetitions, with n being the number of nodes or edges, thus complexity of O(n). I hope I explain my thoughts correctly..

Comment: So, do you mean an O(|E|) using memory for each node?

Comment: Yes, indeed, if you keep track of which edges are are connected to each node, that should be it